# error al leer puerto serial rxtx

Tags: java

Realice una lectura de datos con puerto serial usando la librería `rxtx` el código funciona bien puedo leer e imprimir los datos pero al imprimir el resultado de la lectura no me lo muestra de esta manera 20.60 si no carácter por carácter y adicional a eso quiero asignarle ese valor a una variable `double`  al momento de desconectarme del puerto `COM` pero no consigo obtenerlo este es el código que uso para leer y conectarme.

```
    public class puertoController {

    CommPortIdentifier portId;
    Enumeration puertos;
    SerialPort serialport;
    static InputStream entrada = null;
    Thread t;
    String valor = "COM1";
    private String aux1;

    public void init() {
         t = new Thread(new LeerSerial());
         t.start();
         t.interrupt();
    }

    public void conectar() {
        puertos = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        t = new Thread(new LeerSerial());
        while (puertos.hasMoreElements()) { 

            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) puertos.nextElement(); 
            System.out.println(portId.getName());
            if (portId.getName().equals(valor)) {
                try {
                    serialport = (SerialPort) portId.open("LecturaSerialTemperatura", 500);
                    entrada = serialport.getInputStream(); 
                    t.resume();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void Desconectar() {

        t.interrupt();
        serialport.close();
    }

    public  class LeerSerial implements Runnable {

        int aux;
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    aux = entrada.read();
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    if (aux > 0) {

                        System.out.println((char) aux);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás leyendo letra por letra `aux = entrada.read();`

Lo que debes hacer es leer por el buffer algo así:

```
if(entrada!=null){
    for (; ; ) {
        int index = entrada.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (index < 0)
            break;
        String salida = new String(buffer);
        Double datoDouble = Double.valueOf(salida);
    System.out.println(salida);
    }
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Quedando en tu código así:

```
public class LeerSerial implements Runnable {

    int aux;
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            try {

                if(entrada!=null){
                    for (; ; ) {
                    int index = entrada.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    if (index < 0)
                        break;
                    String salida = new String(buffer);
                    Double datoDouble = Double.valueOf(salida);
                    System.out.println(salida);
                 }
                 Thread.sleep(100);
               }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();//por si hay un error poder saber que ocurrió.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dentro del for que coloco?

Comment: los ; ; por favor

Comment: dentro del for no hay que ponerle parametros?

Comment: No hay necesidad

Comment: disculpa, pero podías acoplarlo a mi ejemplo porque eh tratado y no me imprime nada saludos

Comment: @darksihart ya lo acoplé a tu código.

Comment: me tira un nullpointerexeception aqui  `int index = entrada.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);`

Comment: Es por que no has instanciado entrada, debes ejecutar antes de la lectura el método conectar.

Comment: amigo `conectar();` me arroja método invalido

Comment: amigo si quieres agregame al skype alexandervillalobos12@hotmail.com

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63332/discussion-between-ajeno-and-darksihart).

Comment: una pregunta, si funcionó el código? lo que pasa es que tengo el mismo problema que el amigo que preguntó primero, luego que implementé la solución dada por el otro amigo si obtengo lecturas, pero me sale todo desorganizado, lo implementé justo como está arriba, en la parte que dice "Quedando en tu código así" luego traté de hacer modificaciones pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Alguien sabe qué pueda ser? saludos.

Comment: Para saber bien que problema tienes necesitas colocar tu código has, puedes hacer una pregunta con tu tema particular